# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: -1 while getting data

Tags: flutter, api, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

**I am getting data from the APIs and storing it in the model and displaying it in ProductCardList data but it is showing a range error I dont understand what is the range error while data is received correctly but did not show due to range error if anyone knows about it please let me know thanks in advance**

[image]

```
 Expanded(
            child: GridView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: isMobile(context)? 15.w:10.w, vertical: 8.h),
              itemCount: campaignDetailsModel!.data!.products!.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: isMobile(context)? 2:3,
                childAspectRatio: .75,
                mainAxisSpacing: isMobile(context)? 15:20,
                crossAxisSpacing: isMobile(context)? 15:20,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              //   return Container(
              //     child:     Expanded(
              //   child: Padding(
              //     padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.r),
              //     child: Column(
              //       children: [
              //         Text("${campaignDetailsModel!.data!.products!}"),
                      
                      
              //       ],
              //     )
              //   ),
              // ),
              //   );
                return ProductCardList(
                  dataModel: campaignDetailsModel!.data!.products!,
                  index: index,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),

// ProductCardList class
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:ribbon_widget/ribbon_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:yoori_ecommerce/src/utils/theme_manager.dart';
import '../_route/routes.dart';
import '../controllers/currency_converter_controller.dart';
import '../controllers/home_screen_controller.dart';
import '../utils/app_tags.dart';
import '../utils/app_theme_data.dart';
import '../utils/responsive.dart';

class ProductCardList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductCardList({
    Key? key,
    required this.dataModel,
    required this.index,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final dynamic dataModel;
  final int index;

  @override
  State<ProductCardList> createState() => _ProductCardListState();
}

class _ProductCardListState extends State<ProductCardList> {
  final currencyConverterController = Get.find<CurrencyConverterController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final homeController = Get.put(HomeScreenController());
    return Ribbon(
      farLength: widget.dataModel[widget.index].isNew!
          ? isMobile(context)
              ? 20
              : 30
          : 1,
      nearLength: widget.dataModel[widget.index].isNew!
          ? isMobile(context)
              ? 40
              : 50
          : 1,
      title: widget.dataModel[widget.index].isNew! ? AppTags.neW.tr : "",
      titleStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: isMobile(context) ? 10.sp : 7.sp,
        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
      ),
      color: AppThemeData.productBannerColor,
      location: RibbonLocation.topEnd,
      child: Container(
        height: 230.h,
        width: isMobile(context) ? 165.w : 125.w,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: ThemeController.isDark!
              ? AppThemeData.darkThemeColor
              : Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7.r)),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: AppThemeData.boxShadowColor.withOpacity(0.1),
              spreadRadius: 0,
              blurRadius: 20.r,
              offset: const Offset(0, 10), // changes position of shadow
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Get.toNamed(
              Routes.detailsPage,
              parameters: {
                'productId': widget.dataModel[widget.index].id!.toString(),
              },
            );
          },
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.r),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        widget.dataModel[widget.index].specialDiscountType == 'flat'
                            ? double.parse(widget.dataModel[widget.index].specialDiscount) ==
                                    0.000
                                ? const SizedBox()
                                : Container(
                                    height: 20.h,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: AppThemeData
                                          .productBoxDecorationColor
                                          .withOpacity(0.06),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                        Radius.circular(3.r),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "${currencyConverterController.convertCurrency(widget.dataModel[widget.index].specialDiscount)} OFF",
                                        style: isMobile(context)
                                            ? AppThemeData.todayDealNewStyle
                                            : AppThemeData.todayDealNewStyleTab,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                            : widget.dataModel[widget.index].specialDiscountType ==
                                    'percentage'
                                ? double.parse(
                                            widget.dataModel[widget.index].specialDiscount) ==
                                        0.000
                                    ? const SizedBox()
                                    : Container(
                                        height: 20.h,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: AppThemeData
                                              .productBoxDecorationColor
                                              .withOpacity(0.06),
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(3.r),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                            "${homeController.removeTrailingZeros(widget.dataModel[widget.index].specialDiscount)}% OFF",
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: isMobile(context)
                                                ? AppThemeData.todayDealNewStyle
                                                : AppThemeData
                                                    .todayDealNewStyleTab,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                : Container(),
                      ],
                    ),
                    double.parse(widget.dataModel[widget.index].specialDiscount) == 0.000
                        ? const SizedBox()
                        : SizedBox(width: 5.w),
                    widget.dataModel[widget.index].currentStock == 0
                        ? Container(
                            height: 20.h,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: AppThemeData.productBoxDecorationColor
                                  .withOpacity(0.06),
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3.r)),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                AppTags.stockOut.tr,
                                style: isMobile(context)
                                    ? AppThemeData.todayDealNewStyle
                                    : AppThemeData.todayDealNewStyleTab,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        : const SizedBox(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 18.h,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.r),
                  child: Image.network(
                    widget.dataModel[widget.index].image!,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 14.h),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 7.w),
                child: Text(
                  widget.dataModel[widget.index].title!,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: isMobile(context)
                      ? AppThemeData.todayDealTitleStyle
                      : AppThemeData.todayDealTitleStyleTab,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 5.h),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: isMobile(context) ? 18.w : 10.w),
                child: Center(
                  child: double.parse(widget.dataModel[widget.index].specialDiscount) == 0.000
                      ? Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              currencyConverterController
                                  .convertCurrency(widget.dataModel[widget.index].price!),
                              style: isMobile(context)
                                  ? AppThemeData.todayDealDiscountPriceStyle
                                  : AppThemeData.todayDealDiscountPriceStyleTab,
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      : Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              currencyConverterController
                                  .convertCurrency(widget.dataModel[widget.index].price!),
                              style: isMobile(context)
                                  ? AppThemeData.todayDealOriginalPriceStyle
                                  : AppThemeData.todayDealOriginalPriceStyleTab,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              currencyConverterController.convertCurrency(
                                  widget.dataModel[widget.index].discountPrice!),
                              style: isMobile(context)
                                  ? AppThemeData.todayDealDiscountPriceStyle
                                  : AppThemeData.todayDealDiscountPriceStyleTab,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5.h,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Range error basically means you are trying to print the index which is not in your list. In your case may be your list is empty when you are trying to print. Try to check isEmpty before printing your list data.

Comment: brother thanks for the reply but I have to check it already and there is no empty list while fetching data let me add a picture to the question

Comment: You're getting data but may be you're getting little bit late. So, what I'm telling you is that check isNotEmpty before you're using GridView.builder

Comment: bro I have check it with a condition but still same error

Comment: Can you share what's inside ProductCardList class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249044/discussion-between-noman-hassan-and-rohan-jariwala).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your currency calculator, you were getting invalid value of price range which was generating null value and index was unable to load that null value. This issue is resolved

Comment: Thank you brother my issue was due to currency calculator and i solved it now